# How to convert environment variable to JSON object?

Tags: javascript, json, environment-variables

This is my environment variable:

```
export DATA='{firstName: "OAMAR", lastName: "KANJI"}'
```

`process.env.DATA` sees this as a string but doing something like `JSON.parse(process.env.DATA)` does not work as the keys in the object are not strings. I.e something like `JSON.parse('{"firstName": "OAMAR", "lastName": "KANJI"}')` would work but this is not the form of the environment variable.

Any ideas on how to convert the string to JSON?

Comment: Strings in JSON have to be in double quotes, not single quotes, so `'OAMAR'` is wrong as well.

Comment: Why not just make your environment variable valid JSON? The only thing built-in that will parse something like this is `eval()`, but that's dangerous.

Comment: @Barmar thank you, i will edit that in my question and make a personal note of that. As for entering valid json, it returns an error when I source my .env file

Comment: `export DATA='{"firstName": "OAMAR", "lastName": "KANJI"}'` should not cause an error.

Answer (score 3):

```
export DATA='{"firstName": "OAMAR", "lastName": "KANJI"}'
```

change your format then used like

```
var foo =JSON.parse(DATA);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try converting your string to a valid JSON String then change it back to JSON

```js
const Data ='{firstName: "OAMAR", lastName: "KANJI"}';
const output = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(Data));
console.log(output);
```