How do I define a List environment variable, so I can read it in C#
I have an appsettings.json file with a property which is a list of strings: ["foo", "bar"].
I'm trying to overwrite this property with an environment variable. When I do, I still receive the value from appsettings when I retrieve my variable as a list. If I retrieve it as a string, I receive the environment variable value.
My current code is as follows:
appsettings.json file:
{
  "MyVariable": ["test"],
}

Program.cs file:
var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
            .AddEnvironmentVariables()
            .Build();

If I run the following code without injecting any environment variables, it works.
var result = config.GetSection("MyVariable").Get<List<string>>(); // returns a list with one element "test"

If I add the following environment variable and run again, I still get the same result: A list with one element "test".
MyVariable=["foo", "bar"]
The odd thing is: If I run config.GetSection("MyVariable").Get<string>() it returns this string: MyVariable=[\"foo\", \"bar\"].
How do I define MyVariable as a list, so I can still retrieve it with: config.GetSection("MyVariable").Get<List<string>>()

Does it work when you do .Get<string[]>() instead? I'm suspecting the configuration binder might not properly instantiate the new list.

appsettings.json is not a variable it is a file used for configuration;  perhaps you mean "setting  value" or some such for clarity.   Perhaps you meant to create a class that has a List of strings called "MyVariable" (but with a better name) here.

The most "clean" solution would be to write your own IConfigurationSource. Maybe you can simply use overload with action parameter to add/transform environment variable ?

@MarkSchultheiss "MyVariable" is a json property. I'll correct my question.

@nbokmans .Get<string[]>() behaves identically to .Get<List<string>>().

Your title states "define a list environment variable" but your code seems to point to reading configuration values from JSON files.  Perhaps there is confusion about how all this works here in the default configuration setup/classes?

@MarkSchultheiss I do want to read the list as an environment variable. I load it from the appsettings file when running locally, and want to use the environment variable when running in production. I felt I needed to add the JSON file related code here as well, to explain how my code behaved.

possible duplicates https://stackoverflow.com/q/54372443/125981 or https://stackoverflow.com/q/56277661/125981 or https://stackoverflow.com/q/71613606/125981 or there are a few more also

Thanks for the answers. I ended up with just deserializing the string i retrieved like so:
JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<string>>(config.GetSection("MyVariable").Get<string>())


If this is your solution, please mark it as the solution.

I can't do that until in five hours :D

You need to use an environment variable per item, and the name should contain an index, like this:
MyVariable__0="foo"
MyVariable__1="bar"

From the documentation:

Environment variable names reflect the structure of an appsettings.json file. Each element in the hierarchy is separated by a double underscore (preferable) or a colon. When the element structure includes an array, the array index should be treated as an additional element name in this path.


Is this approach anywhere documented? In source the double underscore is replaced with :, not sure what is MyVariable:0="foo".

I think : is a windows thing. On Linux you have to use __. Correct me if I'm wrong.

__ works cross-platform. : is Windows only. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-7.0#configuration-keys-and-values

@Sinatr I've added documentation to the answer.
